# Split string at hyphen characters too

Tags: java, regex

The line below splits my string on (`.`), (`,`), (`:`) and newline (`\n`) characters.

```
String[] textPhrases = text.split("[.,:\\n]");
```

I need to split on hyphen characters too, but this does not work:

```
String[] textPhrases = text.split("[.,:/-/\\n]");
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is regex. A hyphen has a special meaning inside a character class. You need to place the hyphen as the **first** or **last** item in the class:

```
[-.,:\n]
```

Comment: Usually, one can also escape the hyphen: `[.,:/\-/\n]`. But this might be implementation-defined.

Comment: @Jongware why escape when you don't have to? It just adds clutter.

Comment: If you want to insert the hyphen anywhere, you "have to" :) Yours is a perfectly valid solution, but it requires one to be careful where the hyphen is inserted. Escaping it allows one to place it anywhere.

Comment: ...or escape it `[.,\\-:\n]`. Actually, there is another way - not first, not last and not escaped - that you can specify a hyphen. I'll leave it as a puzzle for you to solve :)

Comment: @Bohemian do you mean using a character range that happens to include the hyphen? It happens that the hyphen falls between `,` and `.` in the ASCII table so `[,-.:\n]` would work.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to split on hyphen characters too, but this does not work...What am I missing or doing wrong?

To answer your question first off on what's wrong in this picture, you have forward slashes inside of your character class around your hyphen. Instead you should be using the escape sequence character (`\\`)

```
[.,:/-/\\n]
    ^^^ Remove these and replace with the escape sequence character (\\-)
```

Within a character class `[]`, you can place a hyphen (`-`) as the **first** or **last** character. You may also escape it (`[.,:\\-\n]`) to add the hyphen in order to be matched.

```
String s  = "hey,hi.foo:bar\nbaz-quz";
String[] parts = s.split("[.,:\n-]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output

```
[hey, hi, foo, bar, baz, quz]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
String[] textPhrases = text.split("[.,:\\-\\n]");
```